# How to analyze a memory leak in Java 1.3

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, weblogic, solaris

I have a WebLogic 7 server, running under j2sdk1_3 on a Solaris platform.
Since Java5, I know the jmap command is very usefull for analyzing and troubleshooting a memory leak.

Is there a similar tool that can be used on Java 1.3?

Comment: Can you update to a newer version of JDK, even on a test platform for diagnosis?

Comment: No, because the leak seems to happens only on a very high load that cannot be reproduced in the test environment. I may have found the problem in my code, and a fix has been made, but I need a tool to analyze the memory and take preventive actions before the system crash.

Comment: It could be that under load the server doesn't keep up with the GCs it needs.  So many bugs have been fixed since Java 1.3 (over the last ten years), I wouldn't assume it's not a bug in the JVM.  BTW I wouldn't update to Java 5.0 or 6 if you can help it, upgrade to Java 7 instead, or wait for Java 8 which should be released this year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-Xrunhprof` option is available on the [1.3 JVM executable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/solaris/java.html). This will generate a heap dump, in either ASCII or binary format, when the JVM exits (whether or not due to out-of-memory). If you have a modern development machine, I believe you can use `jhat` to read the binary format. As noted in the docs, `java -Xrunhprof:help` will tell you what the options are.